# How to make my header logo clickable when using % for the logo in css

Tags: css, header, clickable

I wonder how I can make the header logo on a website that I'm working on clickable while using percentages in the css for the logo. I want to do this without getting rid of the percentages in the css. The website is www.madebyrob.nl.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of **z-index: -1;** you have on your style.css.

Try removing that under #logo and you will have your link working properly.

```
#logo {
    float: none;
    width: 30%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1; /*remove this*/
    top: 0;
    left: 33%;
}
```

Comment: that's a step in de right direction.
but i want to keep the effect of the page scrolling over the logo when scrolling down. Is it possible to make the logo clickable and keeping the z-index: -1; in the css?

Comment: Sorry I can't quite understand what you mean. But if you really need to, you can do it by applying `position:relative; z-index:0` to #logo. Then assign a  `margin-top:-20px; position:relative; z-index:1` to your nav. I don't know if that's what you want though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe clickable?

If you want it to be a link you can just do the following:

```
<a href="">
    <img src="" />
</a>
```

Percentage won't matter

Comment: Yes afcourse. 
I want to be able to click my logo and go to my home page.
It is properly set up with the theme I use (responsive theme for wordpress). But I found out that because I use percentages to center the logo for different screen sizes, the logo isn't click able anymore.

Comment: You can check this website www.madebyrob.nl and inspect the element (chrome).